# How to check installed packages on virtual machine?

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, virtual-machine

I have a virtual machine on my Windows system pc. I wonder if I can get a list of installed programs on the virtual machine. So far I can only get the list on Ubuntu...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to get the list of all packages install in the Ubuntu machine?

Comment: I installed for example MATLAB on virtual machine, but the list I got from 'dpkg' or other commands didn't include MATLAB. So I guess that the Ubuntu (machine) isn't the same as the actually virtual machine?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the list of all installed packages, just run this command in a terminal:

```
dpkg --get-selections
```

to get the list of all packages that are installed or in a transient period (installed, in removal, in installation, etc.).
There are more selections that you can do, and are well explained in the Debian Wiki: [List installed packages](https://wiki.debian.org/ListInstalledPackages)

Answer (score 0):

The **apt** tool on Ubuntu 14.04 and above makes this very easy.

```
apt list --installed
```

Older Versions

To get a list of packages installed locally do this in your terminal:

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep -v deinstall
```

(The -v tag "inverts" grep to return non-matching lines)

To get a list of a specific package installed:

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep postgres
```

Comment: Thanks. It seems I still didn't get the list for the virtual machine, at least MATLAB wasn't on the list...